# cannot concatenate two objects with three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to concatenate two objects ( bar and circle to create a ping pong racket ) in three js ,

I used `var parent = new THREE.Object3D();` but there is no change, and the two objects are still separate

This is My function code :

```js
 function addPaddle() {
    var paddleGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(20, 90, 20, 64, 64),
      paddleMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }),
      paddle = new THREE.Mesh(paddleGeometry, paddleMaterial)
    paddle.rotation.x = 30

    var barre = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 170)

    var materialBarre1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    })
    var barre = new THREE.Mesh(barre, materialBarre1)

    var parent = new THREE.Object3D()
    parent.add(paddle)
    parent.add(barre)
    scene.add(parent)

    barre.rotation.y = 180
    barre.position.x = 100
    barre.position.z = 2000
    barre.position.y = 300
    return paddle
  }
```

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcVbS.png)

Comment: Why do you return `paddle` instead of `parent`?

Comment: when i return the parent , the barre disappear

Comment: Any chance to provide a working code snippet, that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I have added a snippet code of my work , you can see it below

Answer (score 0):

You just have to be more careful with your code and organize it a bit better to find mistakes. For example, you're declaring `var barre` two times, one for a geometry, and again for the mesh. Just create more descriptive **and unique** variable names so you don't confuse them. I would also avoid chaining `var` declarations to make it simpler for you to add/remove individual lines later.

Secondly, if you're grouping the `barre` and `paddle` in a parent, you should return the parent, not just the paddle part.

Here's essentially the same code, cleaned up and organized with unique variable names:

```js
function addPaddle() {
    // Paddle
    var paddleGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(20, 90, 20, 64, 64)
    var paddleMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
    var paddle = new THREE.Mesh(paddleGeom, paddleMat)
    paddle.rotation.x = 30

    // Barre
    var barreGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 170)
    var barreMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
    var barre = new THREE.Mesh(barreGeom, barreMat)

    // Group together
    var parent = new THREE.Object3D()
    parent.add(paddle)
    parent.add(barre)
    scene.add(parent)

    // Transforms
    barre.rotation.y = 180
    barre.position.x = 100
    barre.position.z = 2000
    barre.position.y = 300

    return parent
}
```